What would be the easiest way to show subcategories under specific parents as text links only?
I'm rather new to WP and woo but I'm trying to learn! I have a quick question regarding how categories are displayed and how I may change only certain ones. Here is my issues:
I have a parent category, let's call it US STATES. When clicked on, it will show all 50 states as subcategories, each with a thumbnail image, subcategory (state) name, all in the same style as the parent categories.
The tricky part is, under each state subcategory, I will have hundreds of subcategories for each city in the that state. Rather than having to create a thumbnail for each city, I'd rather just lose all of the formatting and have just text links, probably a row of 10 - 12 at a time, such as: City 1 | City 2 | City 3 | City 4 ...etc.
Is there a way to change all the subcategories under a specific parent to do this?
Thanks in advance!

What you are referring to seems like a theme issue unless layout is being pulled in from a plugin. Without code, it's just shooting blind. If you are not sure where to get the code for showing categories in the theme, try searching the theme directory for category/taxonomy related functions such as get_categories, get_cat_id, get_cat_name and such.

Yes, but if you're referring to categories in WooCommerce you'll need to look for help in their documentation or a more specific forum. This site focuses on custom code only.
If you're referring to categories in Core, you'll need to try a few things yourself and then post the code you're using to get more specific assistance. Typically when you're talking about how things are displayed, that's often in the theme. If you're not using a custom theme already you may need to set up a child theme as your first step so that you can make customizations there, and not change theme files directly.
